# Xcode view hierarchy debugger - "prototyping"

Tags: ios, xcode, autolayout

What does the word "prototyping" mean in the view debugger? It's used to describe a constraint that I didn't add. In IB, the view in question (the upper-left onion image) has an intrinsic width, and its right edge is anchored. It shouldn't need any extra horizontal constraints.

In IB I was designing with a view having simulated metrics set to "Freeform" size, the debugger is showing the view on a 6S. I'm guessing the answer lies in the difference between the two, but can't fathom what's going on.

The added "prototyping" constraint is pulling the onion out of place, towards the left screen edge. Why was it added?

[image]

Comment: Do you have any warnings about missing constraints in Interface Builder?

Comment: No warnings at all! None at runtime either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 'prototyping' constraints are added by XCode Interface Builder when you don't supply enough constraints for it to determine what the layout should be.  If you plan to add constraints later at runtime, which it sounds like you're doing, you can add constraints in IB and set them to be removed at build time.

Just add a constraint for the view's leading edge to superview (even though you don't want it), select the constraint in IB, and check `Remove at build time`.

[image: IB image]

Comment: Sounds plausible... do you know what the grayed out constraints are (in the bottom of the same list with the "prototyping" one)?

Comment: I'm not adding any constraints at runtime. The width of the containing view does change though, so maybe that's triggering something unexpected.

Comment: I believe grayed out constraints are constraints that are present, but inactive.  If you have added enough constraints in IB to determine the layout, I can't explain why XCode would be adding more prototyping constraints.

Comment: Actually, rereading your post, if the onion has an intrinsic width, then maybe a better fix would be to add a width constraint to the onion that is removed at build time (rather than a left edge constraint).  That may more accurately describe the situation.  It shouldn't affect behavior, but it may make more sense to someone looking at it in IB later.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I ended up doing. Odd. Thanks for the help.